# Using a returned array in another function

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function that returns an array and a second function that is supposed to use this returned array, but the program returns saying array is not defined. How can I fix this problem?

```
def popt_reader(filename):
    with codecs.open(popt, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
        rows, cols = [int(c) for c in data_file.readline().split() if c.isnumeric()]
        array = np.fromstring(data_file.read(), sep=' ').reshape(rows, cols)
        return array

def cleaner():
    out = []
    en_point = 0
    for i in range(1,len(array)):
        if np.all((array[i,1::] == 0)):
            pass
        else:
            out.append(array[i,:])
            en_point += 1
    print(en_point)

cleaner(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

You never call the function that returns the array. Try this, just input your own file name

```
...

filename = "my_array_file_here.array"
array = popt_reader(filename)
cleaner(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable `array` is defined within the `popt_reader` function and is not accessible within the `cleaner` function.

Add this line of code before `cleaner(array)` to make it work:

```
array = popt_reader(filename)
```

Which will assign output of `popt_reader` method to `array` variable.

Note that filename should also be defined beforehand

```
filename = "path to file"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a signature(parameter) to the function `cleaner()`

second one should be:

```
def cleaner(array):
    out = []
    en_point = 0
    for i in range(1,len(array)):
        if np.all((array[i,1::] == 0)):
            pass
        else:
            out.append(array[i,:])
            en_point += 1
    print(en_point)

cleaner(array)
```